# how to send function result to temp table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, set-returning-functions

I try to create a temporary table in PostgreSQL from the function result.

this is my funct :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_funct(var_code character)
    RETURNS TABLE(id bigint, name character)
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    
    SELECT Id, Name FROM tbl WHERE Code=var_code;

END;
$BODY$;
```

I Have tried some script but it doesn't work

my script is below :

```
create temp table #tmpTable as select my_funct('xxx');
```

when I ran this script it was shown an error like this *ERROR:  column "my_funct" has pseudo-type record*

Any ideas to achieve this? All thoughts will be appreciated

Comment: Bearing in mind the error text, would be interesting to know the content of that function

Comment: Hi James, the content of my function actually is query to the table like this "SELECT Id, Name FROM tbl WHERE Code='xxxx'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a function returns a record, or set of records, instead of a single result, use the column names that you need or a * to get them all:

```
create temp table #tmpTable as select * from my_funct('xxx');
```